# P&T Assets Url Path

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

Is there a way in P&T Assets to output just the file's relative url path without the filename?

For instance, I'm trying to call a file's retina image.

This is the normal file output:

```
   {image_blog}
          {url}
   {/image_blog}
```

Which results in:

```
   /path/to/file/filename.jpg
```

But I'm looking to obtain this output instead:

```
   /path/to/file/filename@2x.jpg
```

I thought this could be accomplished with...

```
   {image_blog}
          {subfolder}{filename}@2x.{extension}
   {/image_blog}
```

... but this results in ...

```
   filename@2x.jpg
```

What is subfolder supposed to output if not /path/to/file/? Is there another way to grab the relative path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `{url}` or `{server_path}`? I suspect that `{subfolder}` (confusingly) refers subfolders of existing EE File Upload paths (i.e. subfolders that Assets recognizes, but EE does not).

Comment: I never thought I'd use this sentence in my life, but here goes: "Sandwich is right on this one."

Currently there is no great way of accomplishing what you need - subfolder refers to the folder structure within the source already.

Without modifying Assets your best bet would be using another add-on to tweak the URLs or using PHP in this template on template output stage.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to use PHP to grab the relative path from the {url} or {serverpath}, I was just hoping I didn't have to. I work locally and push to production, so it kind of makes it a little more messy than I'd like. Oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using php to grab the relative path by subtracting {filename} from {url}.

```
<?php
    $url       = "{image_blog}{url}{/image_blog}";
    $filename  = "{image_blog}{filename}{/image_blog}";
    $extension = "{image_blog}.{extension}{/image_blog}";
    $needle    = $filename . $extension;
    $relative  = str_replace($needle,"",$url);
    $retina    = $relative . $filename . "@2x" . $extension;
    echo $retina;
?>
```